# Help with understanding the use of を in this sentece

Tags: particle-で

> 言われるままを払った

"I paid as I was told to" Wouldn't it be 言われるままで払った? Are both correct? I mean theres not something called to way I was told that you can pay with right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When まま means "as-is" or "without modification", まま can work as a noun, a no-adjective and an adverb. You cannot say まま**で**:

"to pay as told"

- 言われるまま**を**払う: OK
- 言われるまま**に**払う: OK
- 言われるまま払う: OK
- *言われるまま**で**払う: wrong

"to speak as one feels" / "to describe one's feelings as-is"

- 感じたまま**を**話す: OK
- 感じたまま**に**話す: OK
- 感じたまま話す: OK
- *感じたまま**で**話す: wrong

(～た)まま**で** can be used when a certain state persists for a while:

- 座ったまま**で**動かない
- 座ったまま動かない
- 様子を見に行ったまま**で**連絡がない
- 様子を見に行ったまま連絡がない

Comment: I understood everything but the を particle, why can it be attached to both of the two examples you just said?

Comment: @Irene Because まま is basically a *noun*, as any dictionary monolingual says. But it's hard to directly translate to English..."the same state", "something unchanged"? For example you can say トマトは生のままが美味しい, 生まれたままの姿, 言われたままの金額を払う, etc.

Comment: So for example ビールを買ったままで飲まなかった (The beers I bought still bought/still there, I haven't drank them) is it correct?

Comment: @Irene Yes that's perfectly correct, and 買ったままに飲まなかった is incorrect.

Comment: @naruto "Pay as I was told" can have two meanings. Here you seem to have interpreted it as "pay the amount of money I was told to pay". But, the more common interpretation would be "I payed because you told me to", e.g. Wife: "have you payed electric bill yet?", Husband: "Yes dear. I payed it yesterday just as you told me to". With this interpretation does using で become appropriate?

Comment: @user3856370 In that case you cannot use まま.  You have to say 言われたとおり払ったよ or something like that.

Comment: @naruto so how would you say "I paid the way I was told" to meaning I paid the way my parents taught me?

Comment: @Irene I think naruto's suggestion of  言われたとおり払った would work for that too. This とおり means 'in accordance with' / 'in the same way as' / 'as' etc.

Comment: @Irene 言われたままを払った only refers to the amount of money, but 言われた通り払った is a rather flexible expression and it can refer to the paying method and/or the amount of money depending on the context.